# Confusing output in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

[image]

I'm a bit confused with this simple MATLAB script.

If n = 480 , 1/n should be 0.0020833. How is len_F1 325.63?

Am i missing something here? MATLAB version 2020b

Comment: Are you sure that's all the code you have or is there something in between that you didn't show? Try restarting MATLAB and run again what you have showed above

Comment: This post is caused by a Typo. Please ignore this post. I'm just embarrassed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think that's a lowercase L not a 1. You have defined lowercase L means l somewhere.

Comment: If you believe it is caused by a typo (which it most likely is) then flag the question for typo instead and comment under the question

Comment: this is embarrassing. That was a lowercase L. Sorry lads for wasting your time. Thank you.